# Two datasets in scatterplot connect them with a line

Tags: matplotlib, graph, scatter

Can somebody help me with this problem:

I have two different measurements which I gave value of 0 or 1. Then I made a scatterplot so that all values of measurement 1 are on x=0 and values of measurement 2 are no x=1. Now I want to connect the corresponding measurement 1 and 2 values with a line.
[This is how the graphs looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqp3a.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to provide separate plot commands for each pair of points. Not `scatterplot`, but something like `plot(x, y, marker='o')` for example. Here, `x` and `y` are pairs of points like `[0, 1]` and `[measurement1, measurement2]`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.